# VSCode Sync Workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need help with syncing a workspace.

I usually code in 2 computers because my parents don't live together and right now I'm working on a project and I need to sync the workspace between both computers, I know that git is the best answer but there's a problem:

**.gitignore**

Yes, with .gitignore there will be some files that will be ignored when syncing with git and the answer could be just disabling it but the files that I'm ignoring contains secret code that if someone sees they could destroy my project remotely.

So if anyone can help me sync the workspace between my 2 computers easily without git please tell me.

Thanks, xWalfie

Comment: use a laptop and carry it from A to B and back, or work from a Flash Drive

Comment: me who doesnt have a laptop, cant carry it to school and doesnt have a flash drive

Comment: mail the secret files to yourself and move them over to the other computer, the other files sync with git, put secret files in `.gitignore` and inspect your git status **EACH** time you commit (use command line)